# Excel vba increase cell value without creating circular reference

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet in which cells `D4:D93` are *Data Validation* drop down lists with only `Yes`and `No` as options.

I am trying to figure out how to code VBA so that when `Yes` is selected in a cell in that range, then the value in the coinciding cell in range `I4:I93` changes to be the sum of the coinciding cells in `I4:I93` and `V4:V93`.

I've been searching for days and tried so many things I don't even know where to begin as far as what I've tried. Some attempts resulted in nothing happening. Other resulted in Excel freezing or crashing due to the circular references. Don't know if this is relevant, but `D4:D93` and `I4:I93` are part of a table but `V4:V93` is not.

Answer (score 4):

Try this worksheet event macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim D As Range, rw As Long
    Set D = Range("D4:D93")

    If Intersect(Target, D) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If LCase(Target.Value) <> "yes" Then Exit Sub
    rw = Target.Row
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("I" & rw).Value = Range("I" & rw).Value + Range("V" & rw).Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: That appears to work beautifully. Thank you, I never would have figured that out.